# installing play framework on windows 8

Tags: playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I am trying to install play framework on windows v8.1.  I tried downloading the typesafe activator package and then setup the path in the system environment variables pointing to the extracted directory.  I already have JDK8 and Scala 2.11 on my computer (I tested java -version and scala -version).  However, when I try the following,

```
activator -help
```

the system cannot find activator.  Any thoughts?

Comment: after modifying path do you reopen your command prompt [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100007/install-play-with-activator-on-linux/28908124#28908124) is my answer would help you

Comment: This might be a problem with your path variables. You can find them here:
`Start -> All Apps -> Control panel -> System -> 
    Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment variables` ... could you please post here what you have in the "Path" line?