# Activator: command not found

Tags: java, bash, scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

I am trying to install activator in my linux system.

so first I install java

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

downloaded succefully

then I downloaded activator

```
sudo wget downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.3.4/ypesafe-activator-1.3.4.zip
```

then added path

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/govind/activator-1.3.4/
```

then reloaded bash by

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

then I try to start activator

```
govind@LINUXSERVER:~$ sudo activator
sudo: activator: command not found
```

I tried to print path

```
govind@LINUXSERVER:~$ $PATH
-bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/govind/activator-1.3.4/: No such file or directory
```

but

```
govind@LINUXSERVER:~$ ls /home/govind/activator-1.3.4/
activator      activator-launch-1.3.4.jar  README.html  templates
activator.bat  LICENSE.html                repository
```

but not successfull!! what am I missing??

Comment: does the binary named `activator` exists in the path you just added ?

Comment: Can you please provide the output of following command?
`ls /home/govind/activator-1.3.2/`

Comment: @SriharshaKalluru added in question please have a look

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:/home/govind/activator-1.3.2/` and you put it in 3.4 ?

Comment: @Jahid corrected that

Comment: After correcting , Still you are having the issue ?

Comment: nope, not working but after @monCalamari answer it works

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create a symbolic link to activator:

```
sudo ln -s /home/govind/activator-1.3.4/activator /usr/bin/activator
```

You do not need to edit bashrc profile.

Comment: But which one is a good and safe approach. Using symbolic link or writing down the path in bashrc?

Answer (score 3):

I think the documentation should be fixed.The path still works in earlier versions of activator, but the recent versions don't have executable activator in the mentioned directory. Instead, you can find this inside bin folder.

So for earlier versions of activator

```
export PATH=/home/<user>/activator-dist-1.3.2:$PATH
```

should do, and for recent versions,

```
export PATH=/home/<user>/activator-dist-x.x.x/bin:$PATH
```

/bin is not mentioned in the [play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Installing#macos-unix)

Comment: This should be the correct answer for the new versions.

Answer (score 2):

Superuser may not have `activator` set in `$PATH`. If sudo is indeed required, try

```
sudo /home/govind/activator-1.3.2/activator
```

or sudo copy `activator` to for instance `/usr/bin`. Else the procedure depicted proves valid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

- cd to activityDirectory/bin.
- type ./activator sh command and you will be shown the list of commands you can try
- To create a new project type ./activator [new_Project_name] [Template Name, eg:lagom-java]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

add activator bin path to your .bashrc

you can find the path by

> locate .bashrc

Now if you changed to the home directory where it should usually be, edit this file.

> gedit .bashrc

add this line: export PATH="$HOME/Dev/activator-1.3.XX-minimal/bin:$PATH"
replace X by the correct version number and save this file

> source .bashrc

If opened a terminal window, close it and restart again.

> activator

[image: running activator window]

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

In Centos:-
The activator path is not found that's why you are getting this message. I have used the full path with command and its working fine.

activator/full/path/activator run

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct download link:

```
wget downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.3.10/typesafe-activator-1.3.10.zip
```

the above link had a typo.

Comment: You may need to share a link using the comment section. You will get access to comment once you have enough reputation.

Comment: great, looking forward to that!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Don't ask me why but it got resolved when I removed openjdk-8 and installed Oracle Java 8. Still trying to figure out why but this should be a fix.

For uninstalling openjdk, you can just do:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove openjdk*
```

For installing Oracle Java, you can refer to the following link:
[Installing Java Oracle on your OS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html)